# Hide a div if paragraph does not contain any text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a project using Wikipedia API. Typing a word in seach bar displays a list of items. Like in the picture below. 
[image: Image one]
When a user hover over "more" div an additional content is dispalyed below. like that. 
[image: Image two]

However some items in blue color do not containany information, that is, empty. So i want for those items which do not contain any additional information do not show "more" div. So i have written a code. But unfortunately it does not work.

```
if ($('.list-container>div.titleDesc>p').is(':empty')) {
      $(".show-more").hide();
}
```

Cannot figure out what is wrong so will appreciate any help. If you need more information please refer to my [project](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/zBbxyW) in Codepen.

Comment: Your hover seems a bit buggy as well, it only works when I exactly hover on the left side of the 'more' section.

Comment: You can also use [the :empty pseudoselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

Comment: It is hard to debug so much code. Can't you just check on creaton of the show more button, if there are infos to show?

Comment: Yes i know it work only when user hover over external div. But i think it is trivial to fix it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...the big word there is MINIMAL!!

Comment: Can you please a snippet of you code?

Comment: You can look at my code http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/full/zBbxyW/

Comment: @NZMAI As has been mentioned before, you need to **reduce** the amount of code to just show the issue AND put that code IN THE QUESTION

Comment: Try with `if ($(this).is(':empty'))`, `.text()` doesn't return the DOM element, just a string, and you can't check if a string is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery [:empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) is a selector; hence, it works on ***jQuery elements***. So, you need to update this line:

```
$(this).text().is(':empty')
```

With this line:

```
$(this).is(':empty')
```

Here is a **[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkvKOp)**, I have just updated this JS line, and add a container `div` element.

Comment: Thanks for help! What does debugger mean?

Comment: it's a keyword to debug your JS code, instead of putting a breakpoint(blue arrow) by yourself. Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 $('.list-container>div.titleDesc>p').each(function() {
if ($(this). text() == "" ) {
    $(this). hide() ;
} 
} )
```

You need to use this code after printing searching results

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Anyway thanks for help!